# Next.js form validation with Formik, Yup and React Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-bootstrap, formik, yup

I'm trying to validate the React Bootstrap form using Formik and Yup. Everything is fine form is validating properly but when I refresh the page from the browser then the below error shows:

[image]

This is my contact.js codes:

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, Card, Col, Container, Form, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import Head from "next/head";
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

export default function Contact() {
    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            name: "",
            email: "",
            subject: "",
            message: "",
        },
        validationSchema: Yup.object({
            name: Yup.string()
                .required("Required")
                .min(3, "Must be at least 3 characters"),
            email: Yup.string().email("Invalid email address").required("Required"),
            subject: Yup.string().required("Required"),
            message: Yup.string().required("Required"),
        }),
        onSubmit: (values) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
            formik.resetForm();
        },
    });

    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>Contact Page</title>
            </Head>
            <Container>
                <Row className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center min-vh-100">
                    <Col md={6}>
                        <Card className="shadow">
                            <Card.Header>
                                <h1 className="fw-bold">Contact</h1>
                            </Card.Header>
                            <Card.Body className="p-5">
                                <Form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
                                    <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="name">
                                        <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Control
                                            type="text"
                                            name="name"
                                            value={formik.values.name}
                                            onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                            className={
                                                formik.touched.name && formik.errors.name
                                                    ? "is-invalid"
                                                    : ""
                                            }
                                        />
                                        <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                                            {formik.errors.name}
                                        </Form.Control.Feedback>
                                    </Form.Group>

                                    <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="email">
                                        <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Control
                                            type="email"
                                            name="email"
                                            value={formik.values.email}
                                            onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                            className={
                                                formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email
                                                    ? "is-invalid"
                                                    : ""
                                            }
                                        />
                                        <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                                            {formik.errors.email}
                                        </Form.Control.Feedback>
                                    </Form.Group>

                                    <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="subject">
                                        <Form.Label>Subject</Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Control
                                            type="text"
                                            name="subject"
                                            value={formik.values.subject}
                                            onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                            className={
                                                formik.touched.subject && formik.errors.subject
                                                    ? "is-invalid"
                                                    : ""
                                            }
                                        />
                                        <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                                            {formik.errors.subject}
                                        </Form.Control.Feedback>
                                    </Form.Group>

                                    <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="message">
                                        <Form.Label>Message</Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Control
                                            as="textarea"
                                            name="message"
                                            rows={3}
                                            value={formik.values.message}
                                            onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                            className={
                                                formik.touched.message && formik.errors.message
                                                    ? "is-invalid"
                                                    : ""
                                            }
                                        />
                                        <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                                            {formik.errors.message}
                                        </Form.Control.Feedback>
                                    </Form.Group>

                                    <Form.Group controlId="submitButton">
                                        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                                            Send
                                        </Button>
                                    </Form.Group>
                                </Form>
                            </Card.Body>
                        </Card>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </>
    );
}
```

and this is my _document.js page codes:

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

class MyDocument extends Document {
    static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
        const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;
        // Run the React rendering logic synchronously
        ctx.renderPage = () =>
            originalRenderPage({
                // Useful for wrapping the whole react tree
                enhanceApp: (App) => App,
                // Useful for wrapping in a per-page basis
                enhanceComponent: (Component) => Component,
            });
        // Run the parent `getInitialProps`, it now includes the custom `renderPage`
        const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
        return initialProps;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Html>
                <Head>
                    <link
                        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap"
                        rel="stylesheet"
                        type="text/css"
                    />
                </Head>
                <body style={{ fontFamily: "Poppins, sans-serif" }}>
                    <Main />
                    <NextScript />
                </body>
            </Html>
        );
    }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

I've tried to delete the _document.js file as well but still the same error showing.
Please help me to fix this error.